# Deploying/copying binaries to AWS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there way to programmatically copy dotnet libraries to AWS EC2 instance? the idea is to copy dotnet libraries to EC2 instance and execute unit tests.

Any idea on how we can achieve this?

Comment: Question is this just one instance thats always running? Do you want this to happen at instance startup? And where are the libraries located currently?

Comment: Currently planning on one instance. The binaries are on local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to push your binaries to s3 and then as part of the instance start up have them copy over or prepare a script on the instance using aws cli to copy them over as needed.